# Get the distance between two locations like in the http request in Google Directions

Tags: android, location, directions

I know there are much topics out about this question, but my problem is more specific.
I call the Google Directions http API to get a routing between two locations. The responding JSON has all information how to travel from point A to B. But how can i calculate the distance by myself for example between my actual location and the next end location of a step while im moving? I need the "road line" not the "air-line".

What i did is to get the lat, lng of my actual location with the LocationManager. With this and the lat, lng of the end location i call the Location.distanceBetween method. But it gives a unprecise distance back.. Unprecise means the result of the distancebetween method is different from the distance out of the directions API. For long ways as for short ways.

One solution would be to call the Directions API multiple times... But there must be a nicer work around to get the actual distance along a road. Is there a tool to get what i want?

Edited to make it more understandable

Answer (score 1):

Make a call to the Directions API:

```
 public Document getDocument(LatLng start, LatLng end, String mode) {
    String url = "http://maps.googleapis.com/maps/api/directions/xml?" 
            + "origin=" + start.latitude + "," + start.longitude  
            + "&destination=" + end.latitude + "," + end.longitude 
            + "&sensor=false&units=metric&mode=driving";

    try {
        HttpClient httpClient = new DefaultHttpClient();
        HttpContext localContext = new BasicHttpContext();
        HttpPost httpPost = new HttpPost(url);
        HttpResponse response = httpClient.execute(httpPost, localContext);
        InputStream in = response.getEntity().getContent();
        DocumentBuilder builder = DocumentBuilderFactory.newInstance().newDocumentBuilder();
        Document doc = builder.parse(in);
        return doc;
    } catch (Exception e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
    return null;
}
```

After that you can run on all json objects you have received in the document, and to check the distnace between each pair of points:

```
  public int getDistanceValue (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("distance");
    Node node1 = nl1.item(0);
    NodeList nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();
    Node node2 = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "value"));
    Log.i("DistanceValue", node2.getTextContent());
    return Integer.parseInt(node2.getTextContent());
}
```

and here is how you get all the points:

```
   public ArrayList<LatLng> getDirection (Document doc) {
    NodeList nl1, nl2, nl3;
    ArrayList<LatLng> listGeopoints = new ArrayList<LatLng>();
    nl1 = doc.getElementsByTagName("step");
    if (nl1.getLength() > 0) {
        for (int i = 0; i < nl1.getLength(); i++) {
            Node node1 = nl1.item(i);
            nl2 = node1.getChildNodes();

            Node locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "start_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            Node latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            double lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            Node lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            double lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "polyline"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "points"));
            ArrayList<LatLng> arr = decodePoly(latNode.getTextContent());
            for(int j = 0 ; j < arr.size() ; j++) {
                listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(arr.get(j).latitude, arr.get(j).longitude));
            }

            locationNode = nl2.item(getNodeIndex(nl2, "end_location"));
            nl3 = locationNode.getChildNodes();
            latNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lat"));
            lat = Double.parseDouble(latNode.getTextContent());
            lngNode = nl3.item(getNodeIndex(nl3, "lng"));
            lng = Double.parseDouble(lngNode.getTextContent());
            listGeopoints.add(new LatLng(lat, lng));
        }
    }

    return listGeopoints;
}
```

Actually I used this code to paint a `Polyline` of direction on the map, but the distance function should work as well.

Comment: Your code describes how to get the routing information out of the Directions API Response. But i need to generate tHe distance value to a step/polyline, from the API, from my actual location while moving.